# Jquery how can i stop the select element from dropping down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to stop the user to see the list while clicking select option element :

```
<select name="_users_id_requester">
  <option value="0">-----</option>
  <option selected="" value="774">Asmaa El Habib,Yassine</option>//except this one 
  <option value="779" title="Ahlam Edouiri - U8K8O">Ahlam Edouiri</option>
  <option value="746" title="Ainane Mohamed - MohamedAinane">Ainane Mohamed</option>
</select>
```

i have tried the readonly method , but the problem is i'm using the element within a form , so the form can't read the selected value

Answer (score 1):

Start by giving the select an id.   Perhaps

```
<select name="_users_id_requester" id "requestor" class = "requestorList">
   <option value="0">-----</option>
   <option selected="" value="774">Asmaa El Habib,Yassine</option>//except this one 
   <option value="779" title="Ahlam Edouiri - U8K8O">Ahlam Edouiri</option>
   <option value="746" title="Ainane Mohamed - MohamedAinane">Ainane Mohamed</option>
</select>
```

Then you can easily disable the control

```
$('#requestor').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

To reenable the control:

```
$('#requestor').prop('disabled', '');
```

If you can't set the ID:

```
$('.requestorList').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

To reenable the control:

```
$('.requestorList').prop('disabled', '');
```

Comment: Disabled is a property, not an attribute. You should use `prop()` instead.

Comment: i'm using an existing openSource solution called GLPI , they re using MVC method , and the id are genereted automatically always with defrent value, so just how can i get the element `id` value using jquery ?

Comment: If you do not have control over the IDs generated, you can use alternate selector options.   Such as css class or other attributes.

I will update the answer to show this option and incorporate Alien
Webguy's point.

Comment: the form steel can't read the POST name of the diseabled attr , any another solution ?

Comment: how are you trying to get the value?